# SQL Server query - return values in a column that contain characters other than numbers and other specific special characters

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2019 - we have an `nvarchar` column that contains different date formats, but many with more data than just the date in there, in varying formats.

I need to write a query that will return all columns which contain anything more than/other than numbers, the "/" character, the "\" character, and the "-" character.  Assuming `Column1` and `Table1` names, what does this query look like?

Comment: What does your data look like? Show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will identify all cases where Column1 contains a value not in your allowed characters:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%[^0-9\/-]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are trying to find which rows have bad dates. The "\" is not a valid separator within a date value, but we can account for that with the REPLACE() function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Table1 
WHERE ISDATE(REPLACE(Column1,'\','/')) = 0;
```

Click this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7503f9cba08cb0bc5c0045896a38ad7) to see it in action.